# Is it an acceptable practice to use Parcel to save data in cache?

Tags: android, caching, parcel

**Situation**

My usage for Parcel is to save the following:

1. The list data which can be pulled from the network anytime (More specifically, twitter timeline)
2. The scroll position of the list
3. UI elements' state, such as whether a drawer is open

**Example**

Class A contains the following: ID, Name, Description, Time, Location, and a Bitmap.

ArrayList<A> L contains many instances of A, which are always synced with the internet.

For performance reasons, I wish to store L locally, as a copy of data from the internet in cache, and in a form of Parcel.

**Question**

Is it an acceptable practice to use Parcel to coalesce data and save in cache? Since parcels can be invalidated anytime and also are caches, I think it is fine to do so, but I want to be sure.

Comment: A `Parcel` is not related to a cache, any more than an `EditText` or a `Restaurant` is related to a cache. You may wish to edit your question, explaining in greater detail what you mean by "use Parcel in place of cache".

Comment: @CommonsWare Would the example be fine?

Comment: "Would the example be fine?" -- no, as that does not address anything in my comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe my wording was wrong - I was trying to say that I'd like to coalesce data using Parcel and save to cache, since the data in cache can be disposed anytime.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it an acceptable practice to use Parcel to coalesce data and save in cache?

I wouldn't. You are wasting CPU time for no obvious added value.

> since the data in cache can be disposed anytime

Correct, if by "cache can be disposed" you mean "cache implemented as a singleton can go away as a result of the process being terminated". That is true whether you are caching `Parcels`, `ArrayLists`, or `Restaurants`. Hence, keep your data in its natural form, which is unlikely to be a `Parcel`.

Comment: I am considering the case of app going to background by user, being terminated by the system, and turning on again by user. I have to coalesce in order to save to the storage.

Comment: @Soreepeong: "I have to coalesce in order to save to the storage" -- that is not a `Parcel` is for. Quoting [the `Parcel` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html): "Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable."